# Gutenberg disable the "block" tab in right sidebar

Tags: filters, hooks, block-editor

I'm working on a Gutenberg setup that allows only one classic block.

I want to disable the "block" tab in right sidebar since no settings appear there anyway, but can't find a hook or way to achieve this.

How can I disable the block tab in right sidebar?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered just using the classic editor then?

Comment: I want to use Gutenberg. Classic editor won't be supported in 2-3 years so gutenberg with one block of classic editor works for me

Comment: Did you find out? I'm looking to do the same!

Comment: the classic editor is just a PHP file with a few hooks, why do you want just a single classic block? Could the same result not be achieved by restricting the available blocks to just those possible in the classic editor? ( e.g. paragraphs, images, galleries and headings ). Writers will be able to click a button and convert the classic editor block into multiple normal blocks anyway

Comment: @Willian do not post comments as solutions to questions, it doesn't matter if you don't have enough reputation, the automated system will ban you and flag you as a spambot if you continue